# Windows 10 disables drive access?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-7, windows-10

I had installed windows 7 on one drive, and ubuntu 14.04 on another external drive. I always had full access on my third drive, that is used for all the other stuff, games, images, etc.
Yesterday I did a fresh install with windows 10. Today, when I ran ubuntu again, i weren't able to access my drives. It said something like "windows wasn't shut down correctly".
I also wanna mention, that I have never used the data drive in windows 10.
What is the Problem? What shall I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use sleep / hibernate / hybrid sleep with Windows if you want access to a drive that is being used by Windows.

If you want access to the drive in Ubuntu ... you will need to do a full shutdown "Start / Shutdown/ Shutdown my computer". If you still have issues you will need to disable fast startup located under Power Options then choose what the power buttons do .. then Uncheck the Turn on fast startup (recommended) If all else fails you can try disabling hibernate by going to a admin command prompt and typing `powercfg /h off` which will also disable fast startup but with ssd's it doesn't matter .. my computer boots in like 18 seconds

[image]

[image]

Comment: I always shutdown my computer completely.. The same procedure always worked, when I had Windows 7

Comment: it may be fastboot or whatever its called .... give me a moment i will reenable hibernate so I have the option and i can tell you where you can disable it to check if that solves it for you.. ok its under Power Options then choose what the power buttons do .. then Uncheck the Turn on fast startup (recommended)

Comment: Do you have an image of the settings menu? It is a little bit hard to find, because my windows is in german 

Comment: updated the answer with images hope this helps

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks, i will try It know, with this checkbox disabled

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now. But can you tell me why this is? With windows 7, i always had access to my drivies in ubuntu... 

Comment: it is because this fast startup actually uses something like hibernate to make windows start faster .. because of this .. the files are locked so they cant be changed so the sort of hibernate doesn't get screwed up by differences in files after a restart. I believe this is a new feature of 10 or it may have been introduced in 8.1

Comment: Oh okay. Therefore a big thank you. I am not a windows fanboy, so using my files in ubuntu is essential for me :)